# CSS: responsive layout with divider element gets out of proportion?

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive layout which works fine but the issue that I have is that when I add a simple divider element in my page, everything goes all over the place.

This is a working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/onjL7kn4/3/)

If you stretch the page in the fiddle as much as you can, you would see the issue.

The issue is from this element: `<div class="divider"></div>`

if you remove that element, everything works fine again but I need that divider element and I can't figure out why this happening!

This is my entire code:

```
/* imports */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster);
/* resets */
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* global */

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 95%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
h1 {
  font-family: "Lobster", cursive;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color:#000;
  color:#FFF;
  padding:10px;

}
h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
}

/* grid */
[class*="row-"] {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
[class*="row-"]:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
[class*="col-"] {
}

@media all and ( min-width: 768px ) {

  /* all cols margin */
  [class*="col-"] {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  [class*="col-"]:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  /* make the columns responsive */
  .col-1-2 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-1-4 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    border-left: 1px dotted #e46a10;
    padding:10px;
  }
  .col-1-8 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
  }

  /* 2 span rows */
  .row-2 {
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  .row-2 [class*="col-"]:first-child {
    margin-left: -20px;
  }

  /* 4 span rows */
  .row-4 {
    padding-left: 60px;

  }
  .row-4 [class*="col-"]:first-child {
    margin-left: -60px;
  }

  /* 8 span rows */
  .row-8 {
    padding-left: 60px;
  }
  .row-8 [class*="col-"]:nth-child(4n+1) {
    margin-left: -60px;
  }
  .row-8 [class*="col-"]:nth-child(5n-1) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .row-8 [class*="col-"]:nth-child(6n-1) {
    clear: both;
  }

}


@media all and ( min-width: 1200px ) {

  /* adjust width */
  .col-1-8 {
    float: left;
    width: 12.5%;
  }

  /* 8 span rows */
  .row-8 {
    padding-left: 140px;
  }
  /* reset these... */
  .row-8 [class*="col-"]:nth-child(4n+1) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .row-8 [class*="col-"]:nth-child(5n-1) {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .row-8 [class*="col-"]:nth-child(6n-1) {
    clear: none;
  }
  /* and add this */
  .row-8 [class*="col-"]:nth-child(1) {
    margin-left: -140px;
  }

}


.divider{
display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;

}
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: just place the divider after `.row-4 clearfix` instead of in it, and it works fine

Comment: @shwarp, i know that but i need it to be after col-4 and not after .row which is the container...

Comment: and can you add another container then? around your cols, and put the divider after it? because your issue is due to the float:left of the cols

Comment: @shwarp, i can't really! the elements are being created dynamically inside the .row-4. and .row-4 is the container.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the problem, and here it is:

```
[class*="col-"]:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Since there is no last-child for css class, this code takes in reality the last div in in the `.row` container, so in this case it takes `.divider`!

So if you can, just change the tag of the divider, in `section` for example!

Or instead of `:last-child`, use `:nth-child(n)`

Answer (score 2):

If you are unable to place the `.divider` outside of the `.row-4` container, then you could just add the border to the `.row-4` div itself and remove the `.divider` all together.

**CSS**

```
.row-4 {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onjL7kn4/6/)**

Comment: The divider has a purpose. and its suppose to divide every 4th elements. adding a border to the container doesn't give me the result I need.

Comment: @Jackson, I'll look at it again and try to find a solution that fits your request.

Comment: @Jackson, I have a flexbox solution ready, but it does change a good amount of your code, but it also makes it cleaner and more efficient. Is a flexbox solution something you'd be interested in? https://jsfiddle.net/onjL7kn4/8/